# Calculating the balance for near address 77yen.near

Tags: nearprotocol

When I try calculating the balance for one of the address of Near 77yen.near that does not match to the balance shown in the explorer. Can anyone please help me out here where I am missing the amount to be calculated.

The amount after my calculation is -4.02721 where as in explorer it is 0.35497.

With my calculation from all the transactions shown below total balance transferred to this address is 1066.45154 and total balance transferred from this address is -1070.47875, which becomes -4.02721. Below are the transactions that I considered for calculation. Please let me know where am I going wrong.

https://explorer.near.org/accounts/77yen.near

https://nearblocks.io/address/77yen.near

[Transactions for Near address 77yen.near](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AE45.png)

Tried calculating the balance but that does not match with the balance shown in explorer.

Answer (score 0):

- Account is created: +0.1N [balance ~ 0.1]
- Account is beneficiary of deletion: +0.89 [balance ~ 0.99]
- Income Transfer: +33 [balance ~ 34]
- Income Transfer: +600.66N [balance ~ 634]
- Stake in validator: -634 [balance ~ 0]
- Unstake + Withdraw: +636.95 [balance ~ 636.95]
- Transfer out: -636.95 [balance ~ 0]
- Transfer in: +432.7 [balance ~ 432.7]
- Stake in validator: -432.7 [balance ~ 0]
- Unstake + Withdraw: +433.53 [balance ~ 433.53]
- Transfer out: -433.52941 [balance ~ 0]

Plus minus some fees, the numbers look good to me, since the balance is 0.3 at the end.

Make sure you are taking into account all the NEAR transfers. In many transactions you don't see a `deposit` in the top, but actually `system` is giving back the token not burned for gas, or the validator is sending money back to the user.